# show the numerical labels only in one subsections or entities of multibib package

Tags: moderncv, multibib

uncommenting the following line in moderncv with multibib package show the numerical labels in the bibliography.

```
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
```

But how to show the numerical labels only in one subsections or entities of multibib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by uncommenting that command you've created a global change, but if you want to only do it for specific sections, put:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}
```

Before the sections you want it to be this way, and

```
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\roman{enumiv}]}
```

before those you don't.

This *is* a bit of a hack solution though, and a better way would be to create multiple bibliographies, each with a different style.

You can read more about multiple bibliographies here: [Multiple bibliographies?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multbib)

Comment: Thanks That worked for me and I put the `\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{}`. before those sections I don't want. I don't care if it is a hack solution. The best solution is the simple one.

Comment: Yay, glad to help :). Remember to vote up an answer if its good!